# Link area map from one component to specific ngb-tab in another component

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

In one component I have an img map that has different areas that work as links, in another component I have a tabSet from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/examples , i want that some of the areas of the img map to be linked with specific tabs.

something like : `codificador#idTab1`

**Component with Img Map and Area - href**

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto;">
   <img  src="https://image.ibb.co/koxX8k/MENU2.png" usemap="#menu" border=0>
   <map  name="menu">
       <area shape="rect" coords="202,26,315,119" href="codificador#idTab1"  alt="" title="">
       <area shape="rect" coords="203,153,316,247" href="codificador#idTab2"  alt="" title="">
       <area shape="rect" coords="202,282,315,375" href="codificador#idTab3"  alt="" title="">
       <area shape="rect" coords="411,140,462,260" href="multiplexor"  alt="" title="">
       <area shape="rect" coords="591,140,641,259" href="remux"  alt="" title="">
       <area shape="rect" coords="769,140,819,260"   href="modulador" alt="" title="">
       <area shape="poly" coords="319,68,348,68,348,168,394,168,394,161,410,171,394,180,394,173,341,173,341,74,320,74,320,68"  (click)="ASI1()" alt="" title="">
       <area shape="poly" coords="318,196,394,196,394,190,411,200,394,209,394,202,320,202,320,195"(click)="ASI2()"   alt="" title="">
       <area shape="poly" coords="319,326,342,326,342,227,395,227,394,222,410,231,394,240,394,234,348,234,348,331,319,331,319,325" (click)="ASI3()"  alt="" title="">
       <area shape="poly" coords="466,197,573,197,573,190,592,199,574,209,574,202,466,202,466,197" (click)="TSmethod()"alt="" title="">
       <area shape="poly" coords="645,196,752,196,752,191,769,199,752,208,752,203,646,202,646,197" (click)="BTSmethod()" alt="" title="">
    </map>                
</div>
```

**Here is the tabset in Codificador Component**

```
<ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab id="idTab1"  >
        <ng-template ngbTabTitle> <b> Tab1</b> </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbTabContent  >
            </ng-template>
     </ngb-tab>  
     <ngb-tab id="idTab2" >
         <ng-template ngbTabTitle> <b> Tab2</b> </ng-template>
              <ng-template ngbTabContent  >
              </ng-template>
     </ngb-tab>  
     <ngb-tab id="idTab3"  >
          <ng-template ngbTabTitle> <b> Tab3</b> </ng-template>
               <ng-template ngbTabContent  >
               </ng-template>
     </ngb-tab>  
</ngb-tabset>
```